# Export-Csv into separate columns

Tags: powershell, csv

I want to find computers that have been inactive for 45 days and they are enabled. I have created below code and it works, but when I try to export into a CSV file it puts all the information into one column.

I've tried to use delimiter but still outputs all information into one column.

Here's the code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$inactiveDays = 45
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-($inactiveDays))

Get-ADComputer -Filter {Enabled -eq 'true' -and LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $date -and (Name -like 'WS*' -or Name -like 'LT*')} -Properties Enabled, LastLogonTimeStamp, Name, CanonicalName |
    Select-Object Name, CanonicalName, @{Name='Stamp';Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimeStamp)}} |
    Export-Csv C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Old_Computers.csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: AFAICS the code should do what you want (you could remove `-Delimiter ','`, because it's the default). What exactly do you mean by "puts all the information into one column"? Do you see everything in one column when opening the file in Excel? That is an issue with how Excel imports CSV files. Try exporting to a file with the extension .txt and importing from that text file.

Comment: As stated above, it may be an Excel problem. I've also done this in the same and noticed that Excel shows the data in one column. To be sure you can serialize and deserialize your data. If deserialization works fine it's and Excel issue. Try: ` Export-Csv C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Old_Computers.csv`. Afterwards reimport the data in a PS object via `Import-Csv C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Old_Computers.csv | ft -autosize`. If PS prints the objects with multiple columns (`Name, CanonicalName, Stamp`), than it's an Ecel issue.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I tried exporting into a txt file then importing that into Excel and it worked! Thanks alot!

Comment: mark it as answer then

Comment: Have you tried `-Delimiter ";"` instead of `-Delimiter ","`? I saw that sometimes my Excel auto-formats csv into columns with `";"`

Answer (score 0):

simple solutions is to change -delimiter to ; this will separate values in your excell